# how to get data filled in pdf application dispalyed in angular 5 client side?

Tags: angular, typescript, pdf, client-side-data

I'm able to display fillable pdf application using angular 5 but i'm unable to fetch data or save the file to server along with the data filled.
inside the component:

`import * as $ from 'jquery';`

code used to bind pdf file in html page

`<embed src="http://localhost:4200/FileUpload/i-129.pdf"type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">`

*Thanks!!*

Comment: Whaht language do you use on server side?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidelines, posting a sample of code and editing is needed to ensure a good answer.

Comment: I would guess that this is not possible, as displaying the PDF is handled by the browser and there's no way to interact with the browser's PDF plugin. If you're using any plugin like [pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) please include that in your question

Comment: Just i have injected jquery and used 'object' tag to bind the fillable pdf application but im able to fill data into application when im posting back to server (asp.net webapi 2.0 restful services) empty file is being saved the data which i have filled is not present.

Comment: you have to display pdf and have to send data in server side not a pdf